# Easy way to convert an org.apache.xmlbeansXmlObject to nu.xom.Element

Tags: java, xmlbeans, xom

I have used the `scomp` tool from [XMLBeans](http://xmlbeans.apache.org/) to generate java classes and then populated the fields in an [XmlObject](http://xmlbeans.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/reference/org/apache/xmlbeans/XmlObject.html) (I wrote this code some time ago). I now need to convert this object into the [Element](http://www.xom.nu/apidocs/nu/xom/Element.html) class used by the [XOM library](http://www.xom.nu/).

Is there an easier way than by traversing the `XmlObject` using an `XmlCursor` and then adding child nodes to the target `Element` as you go? I had a look at possibly using some of the `org.w3.dom.*` classes but I'm having trouble finding something that will be easily translatable between the two libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I've worked out a solution which I'll leave here in case anyone else has this problem.

```
public static Element translate(XmlObject o)
{
  org.w3c.Document docOld = (org.w3c.dom.Document) o.newDomNode();
  nu.xom.Document docNew = DOMConverter.convert(docOld);
  return docNew.getRootElement();
}
```